# Is there listeners available like postUpdate, postCreate in Javers

Tags: javers

Is there listeners available in javers which will be invoked before executing a specific operation.

For example, a method like *preUpdate()* which will be invoked before registering an update operation.

I am using javers with [Mongo DB and Spring](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)

PS: Looking for feature similar to [conditional auditing](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/conditional-auditing-hibernate-envers/) in Hibernate Envers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in JaVers and no plans for adding it. You can implement these hooks in standard Spring AOP, for example by providing your implementation of `JaversAuditableAspect`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.